# Android apps developing in Unity - which file should I direct Unity to?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I saw that I need to direct Unity to the SDK file which I want to use in the application(the supported versions of android).
So I got into Edit--> Preferences --> External Tools ---> SDK file location
When I browse, I have a folder called SDK, which contains  many folders in it, including one named "Platforms". There I saw the API version I downloaded from the SDK manager. I got into that folder, I went in the API folder(which is called android- 15), and then I pressed SELECT FOLDER. How ever, it didn't work. 
I tried several different folders and files, but it didn't work as well.
Which file exactly should I direct to, and in which folder will it be?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

scroll to the bottom to download an android SDK standalone and just select this folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should select sdk folder, (the folder whith contains "Platforms" folder )